# Create snap for Kubernetes on Raspberry Pi

Tags: snap, ubuntu-core, arm

I have installed ubuntu core on two Raspberry pi 3's. I want to setup a minimal Kubernetes cluster with one master and one worker node.
I was a bit disappointed that theres no snap for Kubernetes on ARM architecture available.

```
snap find kube

Name  Version  Developer     Notes  Summary
helm  2.6.1    snapcrafters  -      The Kubernetes package manager
```

I know that it's possible to install Kubernetes via snap on x86 platforms.

How do I convert existing x86 snap to ARM?

Comment: There is no way to 'convert'. The source code must be recompiled for the new architecture, and then repackaged in a new snap.

Comment: Okay, thanks. I was hoping that there was some clever way to build a snap out of the existing .deb packages for ARM. Anyway, I ended up with hypriot instead since that dist is even smaller than ubuntu core and also more adopted on RPI's for the moment.

Comment: Ah. 'Use an existing deb' is different from 'convert a snap to a different architecture'. Yes, you can snappify an existing deb - search for 'Snapcraft'

Comment: There are currently a few bugs which prevent us from doing multiple architecture because of how upstream packages bins. https://github.com/kubernetes/release/pull/293